# Codeigniter Undefined property: Welcome::$session and Call to a member function flashdata() on null

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Im using a Codeigniter but why am I getting these error
(1) Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$session
(2) Message: Call to a member function flashdata() on null

Do I need to add something? Thank you

Thank you

Error Screenshot
[image: Error Screenshot]

`Welcome.php` file:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

    function registerNow()
    {

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required|alpha');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('mname', 'Middle Name', 'required|alpha');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required|alpha');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[8]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpass', 'Confirm Password', 'required|min_length[8]|matches[password]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('bday', 'Birthday', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact Number', 'required|numeric');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
                $fname = $this->input->post('fname');
                $mname = $this->input->post('mname');
                $lname = $this->input->post('lname');
                $username = $this->input->post('username');
                $password = $this->input->post('password');
                $bday = $this->input->post('bday');
                $email = $this->input->post('email');
                $contact = $this->input->post('contact');

                $data = array(
                    'first_name' => $fname,
                    'middle_name' => $mname,
                    'last_name' => $lname,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => sha1($password),
                    'bday' => $bday,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'contact_number' => $contact
                );

                $this->load->model('user_model');
                $this->user_model->insertuser($data);
                $this->session->flashdata('success', 'Successfully User Created');
                redirect(base_url('welcome/index'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

call the session on your controller to use session

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Or go to application\config\autoload.php

and add session to the array

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```